# is there any differences between $scope.$watch and $watch?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was learning angular. i didn't get anyhitng from angular documentation can anyone please tell me what is $`watch`

what does it happens if we change that to $`scope.$watch`

sorry i'm new to the anguar this question seem like bit silly....if i'm wrong in knowledge

Comment: As much as I know you can't use $watch without kind of scope. Where did you see that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you watch an expression, you need a context that is used to resolve it. Consider

```
$watch("foo", handler);
```

how should angular know what *foo* to watch? It makes only sense in the context of a scope

```
somescope.$watch("foo", handler);
```

so angular know **what** foo to watch.

But if you are talking about watches in general, many people omit the scope for the sake of simplicity. But you should know: You can't watch for something if you don't know **where** to watch ;)

Comment: tankyou very much i got it

Answer (score 2):

There is not stand alone $watch service. People are saying `$watch` instead of `$scope.$watch` but it's the same. it's just longer to say $scope.$watch, and it's just to mention that even if it's related to $scope he's like a whole new service.

But I may be wrong there's maybe an external stand alone service who's name is $watch, but I don't think so.

Comment: yeah i was just confused '$watch'  and '$scope.$watch'  it seems like there is no '$watch' we have to use it as '$scope.$watch'                                          thanks it was real help for me.....